# how to automatically convert .Rmd file to pdf

Tags: pdf, markdown, rstudio

I would like to automate "knit PDF" functionality in RStudio i.e. conversion from .Rmd file to .pdf. I looked for answers on stackoverflow and found a lot of suggestions, but not really an answer to this specific questions. For example, some suggest using knit2pdf, but knit2pdf requires .Rnw (not .Rmd) as an input, etc. One workflow I found here [http://rprogramming.net/create-html-or-pdf-files-with-r-knitr-miktex-and-pandoc/](http://rprogramming.net/create-html-or-pdf-files-with-r-knitr-miktex-and-pandoc) uses:
(1) knit to convert from .Rmd to .md (2) markdownToHTML to convert
from .md to .html and (3) pandoc to convert from .html to .pdf,
so in principle accomplishes what I want, but result is not the same as from
"knit PDF" in RStudio (and suboptimal).

Comment: And what's your question, exactly?

Comment: Please use https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf / knitr package will allow you to convert from rmd to html or pdf without the intermediate conversions

Comment: My question is how to do this conversion **automatically** [e.g. in R script, or RStudio script (if such exists)] without RStudio GUI and clicking "knit PDF" button.

Comment: I would like to be able to do it automatically on large number of .Rmd files (ideally from R script) without opening them manually in RStudio, clicking on "knit PDF", opening next one, etc. I hope you got the picture...

Comment: rmarkdown::render looks promising, but when I run it on one of the files I get an error: ! Package amsmath Error: \bar allowed only in math mode.
See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.313 \bar\{
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Comment: After some experimentation it turns out that rmarkdown::render works well with pandoc 1.13.1 (from RStudio install), but it fails with pandoc 1.15.2, which I installed separately.